# Filtering date With SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have table like this:

```
customer_id    date    order_id
12           1/11/2021     2
12           22/11/2021    3
12           31/11/2021    5
42           1/11/2021     2
42           15/11/2021    2
42           31/11/2021    2
43           22/11/2021    1
43           25/11/2021    2
```

Yemen I want to select only the `customer_id` that are 30 days between their first and last purchase, Then make a join with the product table, which means something like this:

```
customer_id    date    order_id   Product_name
12           1/11/2021     2         apple
12           22/11/2021    3         car
12           31/11/2021    5         orange
42           1/11/2021     2         apple
42           15/11/2021    2         apple
42           31/11/2021    2         apple
```

for example:

```
select customer_id, date, order_id, product_name
left join product on order_id = product_id
where customer_id.max(date) - customer_id.min(date) = 30
```

Comment: What date is `31/11/2021`?

Comment: All data shown falls between the first and last purchase per customer within 30 days.  Can you extend your sample data set to get the point across?

Comment: I have expanded my example, if you pay attention to the second table, there is only the customer ID, which is 30 days between the first purchase and the last purchase.

Comment: Date 31/11/2021 is just for example

Comment: @AminJebeli November does NOT have 31 days - that's the point of the comment.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

If I understand you correctly and you want to select only the customers IDs, a statement using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` and `DATEDIFF()` is an option:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM (VALUES
   (12, CONVERT(date, '20211101'), 2),
   (12, CONVERT(date, '20211122'), 3),
   (12, CONVERT(date, '20211130'), 5),
   (42, CONVERT(date, '20211101'), 2),
   (42, CONVERT(date, '20211231'), 2),
   (43, CONVERT(date, '20211122'), 1)
) t (customer_id, date, order_id)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING DATEDIFF(day, MIN(date), MAX(date)) = 30
```

Result:

```
customer_id
12
43
```

**Update:**

It seems, that you need the orders information, not the customers IDs:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders o
JOIN Products p ON o.order_id = p.product_id
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM Orders
   WHERE customer_id = o.customer_id
   GROUP BY customer_id
   HAVING DATEDIFF(day, MIN(date), MAX(date)) = 30
)
```

Comment: What do I need to do if I want to use this query to join another table called a product?

Comment: @AminJebeli, post the additional information and sample data in the question, or ask a different question.

Comment: I added new information to the question

Comment: @AminJebeli, use a `JOIN`. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Select original rows matching the criteria

```
select customer_id, date, order_id
from 
    (select customer_id, date, order_id
     , max(date) over (partition by customer_id) dmax
     , min(date) over (partition by customer_id) dmin
     from myTable
    ) t
where date in (dmax, dmin) and datediff(day, dmin, dmax) = 30
```

and join the output and `Products` on order_id = product_id

```
select s.*, p.product_name
from (
    select customer_id, date, order_id
    from 
        (select customer_id, date, order_id
         , max(date) over (partition by customer_id) dmax
         , min(date) over (partition by customer_id) dmin
         from myTable
        ) t
    where date in (dmax, dmin) and datediff(day, dmin, dmax) = 30  
) s
join Product p on s.order_id = p.product_id;
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I guess OP means 30 days _or more_.

Comment: @jarlh, .. quite possible, just replace '=' with '>=' in the query

Comment: I added new information to the question, please check your answer again and edit if it need

Comment: @AminJebeli, added the join to get product_name